# Просвечивающий изображение блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

Подобных вещей еще не приходилось реализовывать, по этому нуждаюсь в помощи выбора оптимального способа реализации.
Постараюсь максимально понятно объяснить, что нужно сделать.
Есть блок с изображением, при попадании курсора в область этого блока, курсор заменяется  на прямоугольный блок (возможно прозрачное изображение с рамкой), под которым начинает просвечиваться блок с изображением, а под ним в свою очередь, находится другое изображение часть которого становится видна. Получается что-то вроде `clip-path` как здесь http://www.cssplant.com/clip-path-generator только вместо белого фона другое изображение и желательно иметь возможно как-то стилизовать просвечиваемую область, возможно даже размещать в ней какие-то еще элементы. Также на заднем фоне, есть активные области и если они попадают в область просмотра под курсором, нужно это отлавливать.
Предполагаю, что нужно смотреть в сторону canvas'a. Если вдруг кто-то реализовывал подобное или имеет понятие как это можно осуществить, возможно знаете готовые библиотеки для подобных решений, буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Что-то подобное соорудил на `svg` + `js`

Эффект достигается за счет `clip-path` и подсчета расстояния от курсора до активных зон.

```js
// точка, для пересчета координат мыши в координаты svg холста
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

// активные зоны
var zones = document.querySelectorAll('.zone');

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

  // так получаем координаты мыши относительно холста
  pt.x = e.clientX; 
  pt.y = e.clientY; 
  let p = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

  // позиционируем clip-path
  clipRect.setAttribute('x', p.x - 7.5);
  clipRect.setAttribute('y', p.y - 17);
  
  // позиционируем телефон
  phone.setAttribute('x', p.x - 12.5);
  phone.setAttribute('y', p.y - 25);
  text.setAttribute('x', p.x);
  text.setAttribute('y', p.y + 13);
  text.innerHTML = '';
  
  // перебираем все зоны
  zones.forEach(z => {

    // текущая прозрачность активной зоны
    let o = z.style.opacity;
    
    // новое значение прозрачности на основании теста попадания круга в прямоугольник
    z.style.opacity = test(z, clipRect) ? 1 : 0;
    
    +z.style.opacity && (text.innerHTML = z.id);
    
    // если значение прозрачности изменилось с 0 на 1 вызываем callback
    +z.style.opacity - o === 1 && callback(z.id);
      
  })
  
})

function test(zone, rect) {
    var zx = +zone.getAttribute('cx');
    var zy = +zone.getAttribute('cy');
    var zr = +zone.getAttribute('r');
    var rx = +rect.getAttribute('x');
    var ry = +rect.getAttribute('y');
    var rw = +rect.getAttribute('width');
    var rh = +rect.getAttribute('height');
    return zx - zr > rx && zx + zr < rx + rw &&
           zy - zr > ry && zy + zr < ry + rh;
}

function callback(id) {
  console.log(id)
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" height="100vh" id="svg" style="cursor:none;">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/400" width="200" height="100"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/2/800/400" width="200" height="100"/>
      </pattern>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <rect id="clipRect" width="15" height="34"></rect>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect width="200" height="100" fill="url(#img1)"></rect>
    <rect width="200" height="100" fill="url(#img2)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></rect>
    <circle id="zone1" class="zone" cx="20" cy="20" r="2"></circle>
    <circle id="zone2" class="zone" cx="50" cy="70" r="4"></circle>
    <circle id="zone3" class="zone" cx="120" cy="30" r="5"></circle>
    <circle id="zone4" class="zone" cx="150" cy="80" r="3"></circle>
    <image id="phone" width="25" height="50" 
           xlink:href="https://www.searchpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Apple-iPhone-XR-715x1090.png"></image>
    <text id="text" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="5" fill="white"></text>
    <style>
      .zone {
        fill:red;
        opacity:0;
      }
    </style>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Было бы здорово ещё несколько коментариев по коду, как оно работает

Comment: @DmitryDavydov написал комменты

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95918/discussion-between-kost1k-and-stranger-in-the-q).